# gwt mvp pattern with activities and gin

Tags: java, gwt, gwt-mvp

i am new to GWT MVP.I have read MVP documentation provided on Google site and also searched on other sites.
But i am getting confused with MVP  ,activities and gin .Can u please suggest me some good sites which have provided good explanation on it with complete example. 
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

I have a simple example of using GIN with Activities and MVP, in the form of a Maven archetype (but the code should be simple enough that you can read it without using Maven / the archetype) at: https://github.com/tbroyer/gwt-maven-archetypes/tree/master/guice-rf-activities/src/main/resources/archetype-resources/__rootArtifactId__-client/src/main/java

Answer (score -1):

GIN is a mainly a GWT-based version of the Google’s homegrown dependency injection framework [GUICE](http://code.google.com/p/google-guice/).

But because the GWT applications run on top of the browser JavaScript engine instead of on the JVM, some of the GUICE features are not available in GIN.

You can  find the clear explanation   [HERE](http://www.canoo.com/blog/2011/04/05/gwt-dependency-injection-recipes-using-gin/)

The official GWT website itself documented the `GIN   Tutorial`

The below link will redirect you to the Getting Started tutorialto the GIN

http://code.google.com/p/google-gin/wiki/GinTutorial

And  you can find the sample  code related to the same example in the below link

http://code.google.com/p/google-gin/source/browse/#svn%2Ftags%2F2.0.0%2Fsamples

Comment: I don't think this answer effectively answers the question. I understand GIN quite well. Activities and Places with GIN is really hard to get the grips with. Like the answer better.